# How to solder these tiny pogo pins?

Tags: soldering, pins, testing, test-equipment

I bought pogo pins to use for firmware uploading.

So I have to make a Jig for my PCB,
but this is the first time I use pogo pins. 
I have no ideas where I have to solder, I mean I want to know if pogo pins have a direction for soldering.

as far as I know Gold surface is for better current conduction so I think Gold end is for contact point, but in this picture It seems silver end is for contact point; I'm a little confused.

1. How can I make a Jig for this tiny one? (I use 2.54 mm gap for Test point on PCB)
   and
2. what is the direction of soldering for this Pogo pins?

[image]

Comment: Silver is a better conductor than gold. If you google pogo pins and look at the hundreds of images, you'll figure it out.

Comment: @Andyaka Oh, This is very important information, I didn't know about this before you told me. you are right Silver has a better conductive than Gold. I found that conductivity level Silver > Copper > Gold. Thank you so much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The inner part of the Pogo pin, silver colored in your picture, is what contacts the workpiece.  In many styles it has a broader head or a special shape.

You are not actually supposed to solder to pogo pins, but rather insert them in sleeves.  The sleeve for a P75 pin for example is an R75.  The sleeves come with either a solder tail or what is effectively a wire wrap post, or may be available prewired to cable. Tiny heatshrink works well.

The advantage of the sleeves is that when a Pogo gets bent or starts sticking in the compressed position you can carefully pull it out and push in another without having to rewire.

That said if you want to use only what you have you can carefully solder to the back of the outer part of the pogo just below the end.  It's probably better if you don't get solder in the hole.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, so I've searched about pogo pin sleeve or pogo pin socket, but I couldn't find R75 socket in Ali express. can you recommend web site or product names for this? and in my case I think I can make solder socket using my 3d printer so I want to see the drawing or pictures of sockets or sleeves.

Answer (score 0):

Pogo Pin sockets are called "receptacle" and can be found with the same vendors that also sell the probes. I haven't heard the name sleeve before.
I just know a couple of them in Germany, such as [Tekon Prueftechnik](https://www.tekon-prueftechnik.de/en/) or Ingun.

or directly in Asia from the source CCP Contact Probes:
[CCP Contact Probes](https://ccpcontactprobes.com/ict-test-probes)

There are hundreds of vendors for these probes, you can probably also find it on ebay.

Regarding the soldering issue. You can solder the probe directly at the bottom of the Barrel. You don't necessarily need a receptacle unless you plan to test large quantities and will regularly change the probe.